# ReactJS's setState confusion with select drop down

Tags: jquery, reactjs, select, setstate

I'm getting a mis-ordered response in React's setState with a select drop down I'm using. It's giving me the value of the previously selected option. When I first select something it comes out as blank, but the second select will give me the one I chose before.

So, first pick: "Green" results to empty
Second pick: "Red" will give me 'gre' as result

I know I'm missing something, perhaps I'm not binding it correctly?

```
class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          typeValue: ''
        }
     this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler;
     this.expressValue = this.expressValue.bind(this);
    }

    expressValue(e) {
       this.setState({
           typeValue : e.target.value
       });
       console.log('this type val state is: ' + this.state.typeValue);
    }

    render() {
         return (
            <div>
                <TypeSelect changeHandler={this.expressValue} />
            </div>
         )
    }
};

class TypeSelect extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }

   render() {
        let options = {
           'default': 'Choose a category',
           'red': 'Red',
           'blu': 'Blue',
           'gre': 'Green',
         }
       return (
            <select name="name_type" id="name_type" onChange={this.props.changeHandler}>
            {
                  Object.keys(options).map(function(key){
                   return (
                       <option key={key} value={key}>{options[key]}</option>
                     )
                 })
               }
           </select>
     )
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState()` changes the state asyncronously. It means, the value will be really changed with a bit delay. Usually it's not a problem, when you are relaying on `state` after compomemnt update. But there you are trying to take a new value immediately. This won't work, as at this time you still don't have this value in the `state`. In your particular case there are two ways.

**First way**. Use your origin value instead of state value in `expressValue` function:

```
expressValue(e) {
   this.setState({
       typeValue : e.target.value
   });
   console.log('this type val state is: ' + e.target.value);
}
```

**Second way**. Show the message after the compoment was updated, for example, in `render` method, wich is calling every time the `state` was changes.

```
render() {
     console.log('this type val state is: ' + this.state.typeValue );
     return (
        <div>
            <TypeSelect changeHandler={this.expressValue} />
        </div>
     )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Roman's got it right, but I also wanted to point something else out:

this.changeHandler is not defined in your Main react component. And even if it was, you didn't bind it to (this).

In your constructor, change the line:

```
this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler;
```

to:

```
this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
```

and then you would define a function by that name as you did expressValue().

Comment: Binding the `changeHandler` gave me an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

Comment: It will be defined once you write the function. So above expressValue(e) {..., if you wrote 'changeHandler(e){console.log(e)};', this.changeHandler would no longer be undefined.

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't see this function in that component at all neither don't see it's usage anywhere. You may remove this row, it's useless.

Comment: `changeHandler` is used as props reference for the onClick function

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. When you pass a function as props to a component (using es6 class constructors, which you are), that function needs to be bound to the component where it originated (conventionally done in the constructor() method). However, without actually writing the function, this.[functionName] is undefined, and you you can't call bind() on undefined. This is a very common error, and one that many people initially have trouble debugging. In your example, this.changeHandler is undefined, and you are then setting its value to undefined. Fortunately, you aren't actually doing

Comment: anything else with it, so you won't experience any errors. When you return a component in the render() method, and you define its props as you have: changeHandler={this.expressValue}, 'changeHandler', here, has nothing to do with the parent component. The value assigned to it (in this case this.expressValue) will be passed to the child component as a prop(erty) with the key 'changeHandler'. You could rewrite that to <TypeSelect undefined={this.expressValue}.../> and it would work so long as you called this.props.undefined().